# How to disable "sender non-delivery notification" in postfix?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, email-bounces

I want postfix to **stop** sending non-delivery notifications to my local account, here is example from  my log

```
17:47:08  A727B62C6F61: message-id=<20121124174708.A727B62C6F61@mail.***********>
17:47:08  F151362C6F5F: sender non-delivery notification: A727B62C6F61
17:47:08  A727B62C6F61: from=<>, size=4676, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
17:47:08  F151362C6F5F: removed
17:47:08  warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
17:47:08  A727B62C6F61: to=<**********>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, ...
```

How can I configure this in my main.cf?

Comment: if you show us the full log of F151362C6F5F we might see why these bounces are generated in the first place and help you fix the real problem. disabling bounces is not the solution and strongly discouraged.. bounces are an important part of the email system.

Comment: He's not asking to disable bounces; he's talking about bounce *notifications*, which are configurable.

Comment: @adaptr yep, this smart-assing about "you need to fix the root issue" while not seeing that bounce != bounce message has misled people away from working towards the answer...

Comment: I think every MTA‌ need to bouncing.

Answer (score 13):

The answer:

master.cf

```
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
```

should be changed to:

master.cf

```
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       discard
```

Comment: Some explanation of WHY is is bad should be given please, downvoters.

Comment: Rewrote [comment from Gryphius](http://serverfault.com/questions/452013/how-to-disable-sender-non-delivery-notification-in-postfix?rq=1#comment493404_452013)

This solution will be disable bounce service, it is not the solution and strongly discouraged as bounces are an important part of the email system. Instead you should investigate why these bounces are generated in the first place and help you fix the real problem.

Comment: @masegaloeh That is not a good reason, because in my case the bounce reason is pulled from the logs and the bounce message is a waste of resources. Totally not helpful of you to discourage an answer because it does not fit your, but other people's use case.

Answer (score 5):

To control where bounce notifications are sent, and when, look at the following settings:

```
bounce_notice_recipient
notify_classes
```

Both are described here: http://www.postfix.org/bounce.8.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow me to cancel the notification only configure it to  be sent to a place or configure what to report, I will do some testing with setting those setting to empty values and report back

Comment: `notify_classes=`

Comment: @adaptr: It doesn't seem to work. Leaving notify_classes empty will force postfix to return to default value (as it seems to me). I have similar problem as David.

Comment: @koressak: try setting `notify_classes=" "`, explicitely setting a string value consisting of one space character worked for me

Answer (score 4):

The [postconf docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes) list 8 types of notify classes: `bounce`, `2bounce`, `data`, `delay`, `policy`, `protocol`, `resource` and `software`. I suggest the following:

```
notify_classes = 2bounce, data, delay, resource, software
```

You get notifications about bounced undeliverable mail, problems of postfix (`data`, `resource` and `software`) and mail that couldn't be delivered for technical reasons (can indicate a problem on your side, `delay`).

`bounce` and `policy` would notify you about rejected/bounced mail, and `protocol` about spammers or alike (they violate SMTP protocol)

Comment: The error class `data` has been supported since postfix 2.9.