# Postfix: disable "sender non-delivery notification" from MAILER-DAEMON

Tags: postfix

Is there is a way to prevent postfix from sending them to the sender? My boss asked me to do so, so I'm not going to argue with him, just need to disable it.

I've tried to discard them in header_checks, by filtering "From: MAILER-DAEMON" field, but originally these mails were send "from=<>"  and then it will be replaced to MAILER-DAEMON after mail passes  header_checks. Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer here [How to disable "sender non-delivery notification" in postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/452013/how-to-disable-sender-non-delivery-notification-in-postfix?rq=1) Even it was downvoted, but works for me

The answer:

master.cf

```
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
```

should be changed to:

master.cf

```
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       discard
```